# Usage of Vue.js with XHTML

Tags: vue.js, xhtml, xml-namespaces

In a page which uses Vue.js there are often attributes whose names have a colon as their first character or somewhere in the middle (e.g. after `v-bind` or `v-on`). Those starting with a colon aren't namespace-well-formed per [Namespaces in XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/), and for those having some prefixes before the colon those prefixes are required to be declared with the `xmlns:prefix` syntax. And there's even a possibility of starting an attribute name with `@`, which even plain XML already forbids.

Therefore, is it at all possible, and so, how practical, to use Vue.js in an XHTML document? Can just a subset of its features be used? Or do there exist simple workarounds for the above problems, enabling all of Vue.js's power in a straightforward and interoperable way?

Comment: `@` and `:` are shorthand for v-bind and v-on. They are syntactic sugar that gets compiled into html that conforms to the html spec.

Comment: So they exist only on the server side, @bassxzero? In templates, whose syntax is custom, not HTML, XML or SGML, just similar (with those weird things resembling attributes)? And the served representations can indeed be HTML, XHTML, SVG, or anything like it?

Comment: Correct. The template are parsed and generate valid HTML which is served to your browser.

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered a problem where I had to combine Vue.js and XHTML. I I typically use Vue.js and html daily in my projects, but suddenly I found myself in a situation where I needed to integrate it with XHTML.

one of sample problem is

```
<input id="test" name="test" v-on:click="test()" />
```

XHTML would detect this code `v-on:click="test()"` as an **error**

my solution is to add that attribute via JS native after XHTML finished rendered

**XHTML**

```
<input id="test" name="test" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
document.getElementById("test").setAttribute('v-on:click', 'test()');
setTimeout(function(){
   // execute Vue process
},100);
```

Basically, the flow is to initially follow valid HTML, and then make adjustments to the HTML after it is rendered

the following is full snippet code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Vue.js  Example</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
    <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
    <h1  id="welcome" >Click me!!</h1>
    </div>

    <script>
    document.getElementById("welcome").setAttribute("v-on:click","test()");
    setTimeout(function(){
        new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                message: 'Hello, Vue.js!'
            },
            methods:{
                test:function(){
                    alert('test!');
                }
            },
            mounted() {
                console.log('Component mounted');
            }
        });
    },100)
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```